# Help with formula for musical instrument

Tags: frequency, vibrations, moment

The formula is:

$$ f = \frac{3.5161}{2\pi L^2}\sqrt{\frac{EI}{\rho A}} $$

$A$ = area, $\rho$ = density, $I$ = second moment of area cross section, $E$ = Young's modulus, and $L$ = length.
Can anyone help transpose this equation so that A is the unknown subject?

I can't find my way around it, and the people I've asked are stumped?

So i have some sprung steel, I'm calculating the frequency to make a SPECIFIC note.... but i want to know what size I need my steel (rectangular rod) to be to create the desired note/frequency.

Am I looking at it all wrong?

Comment: Please check that the edited formula is still correct.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Mark. Sorry I'm new to this, and very rusty with the old engineering maths.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what instrument is this for? Xylophone?

Comment: I'm a craftsman, it's a mixture between a Kalimba (Mbira) and a Cajon drum. I want to be as accurate as possible making the Steel "keys". 
Unsure about the Length. I've been working on various tests all week.

Comment: Related : [Why aren't the lengths of the bars on a toy glockenspiel proportional to the wavelengths?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269669)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ f = \frac{3.5161}{2\pi L^2}\sqrt{\frac{EI}{\rho A}} $$
$$ f^2 = \left(\frac{3.5161}{2\pi L^2}\right)^2\frac{EI}{\rho A} $$
$$ Af^2 = \left(\frac{3.5161}{2\pi L^2}\right)^2\frac{EI}{\rho} $$
$$ A = \left(\frac{3.5161}{2\pi L^2}\right)^2\frac{EI}{\rho f^2} $$
or
$$ A = \left(\frac{3.5161}{2\pi L^2f}\right)^2\frac{EI}{\rho} $$

Comment: Mark H, extremely helpful, the workings out makes it perfect to revise. 
You've really helped me out, thank you.