# Vibrating string - presentation suggestions

Tags: experimental-physics, acoustics, education, string, vibrations

I will present a faculty work on the "Vibrating String" in a discipline of Experimental Physics. I needed something that was "out of the box" for the completion of the work, to make a good impact, but I do not know what I can add. The support of the work is in powerpoint. I accept suggestions please.

Comment: Please ask a specific question about physics instead of asking for suggestions for a presentation - the latter invites opinion-based answers where no uniquely "correct" answer can be identified.

Comment: @ACuriousMind For me all the answers are right, but I needed the opinion of someone with experience, because I do not know what to do at the end of the presentation. And there will be more than one group presenting this theme. I need our group to stand out somehow.

Comment: +1. I think this question should be reopened. Although asking for suggestions the topic has been narrowed down to "the Vibrating String"  in experimental physics, and seems to be asking for an attention-grabbing demonstration. I do not think this is "too broad".

Comment: @sammygerbil   How this is fundamentally different from asking for help on a homework question where the OP has provided no evidence of effort?  To put it differently: where is the conceptual difficulty here?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I have looked for many phenomena like the experience of Young's split double, the interferometry, but I do not know if they are related to the experience of the vibrating string. I would like to know of some phenomenon that could be directly related, which would best describe the experience. I'm struggling, I've looked everywhere, but the only ones I remembered were those two described above.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Does the homework tag apply here? I think not. Generally, although effort is encouraged, lack of effort is not (officially) a reason for closing a question. Asking about a conceptual difficulty is not a general requirement either (eg resource recommendations). I am not claiming this is a great question, only that it is not "too broad".

Comment: I'm not asking them to do my homework. This is a group work for an oral presentation to the university. My question is: I would like to know which are the processes most directly related to the vibrating string, I would like to know the best applications / comparisons with the vibrating string.

Comment: @sammygerbil This is clearly a school-related presentation: I would classify it as a homework question and we have minor differences of opinion.  There is a multiplicity of good questions on the topics directly related (as presented on the right panel), and with a bit of effort one can find plenty of additional material on this site, including this famous question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268568/why-are-the-harmonics-of-a-piano-tone-not-multiples-of-the-base-frequency/268571#268571.   Moreover, "best applications" is clearly a matter of opinion.  I will abstain from voting.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Probably your question will not be reopened. Zero is right about there being plenty of ideas on this site if you search for them - eg using "guitar" or the tag [acoustics]. It is not clear if you are asking for a demonstration, or an analogy, or something else. If you edit your question to make it more specific what you want to know, it might get reopened. (I know you have made further comments, but these will only influence votes to reopen if they are edited into the body of your question.)

Comment: Have you found an answer? Or can you copy and paste it on Matter Modeling SE (please)?